# Moving a Blue Whale

Tags: science-based, fauna, flight, transportation

## I need to move a blue whale.

**Goal: Move a blue whale out of the water, somehow, and return them to the water safely, as the area they live in is no longer capable of sustaining them in my world.**

**Conditions**

1. Any methodology must not conflict with current known physics.
2. No animal abuse/cruelty allowed.
3. Ensure the whales are conscious throughout the journey.
4. They will be travelling roughly 17 miles.
5. It doesn't matter if they are enclosed.
6. They must remain at least 50 feet from the water at all times.

#### Question:

*How do I keep them alive, following these guidelines?*

Comment: Does it need to be exposed directly to the stratosphere or can it be enclosed and potentially still immersed in water?

Comment: This is what we (as humanity) managed to do with whales so far: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYyU3USJ-8E

Comment: @DanSmolinske there is no restriction on this so long as the animal can be kept conscious and alive. Enclosure or not is your say but the animal must be physically up there.

Comment: @PavelJanicek that video is co-operation between us and animal, now this is one-sided operation.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that taking a creature from its local habitat and launching it into the stratosphere for no reason IS animal abuse.

Comment: @user6760 I've got a solution using a giant elastic band and parachutes, but the whale dies with a sonic boom at launch time.  Can you find a few more volunteers for me?

Comment: @Twelfth that's a classic example of animal abuse/cruelty, I encourage you to go for counseling and that being said I've managed to convince 6 more adult blue whales... no I must resist this temptation...

Comment: Items 2 and 4 also rule out the 'infinite improbability drive' approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blue whale weighs up to 200 metric tons. The statosphere starts 15'000 meters above ground.

The [Antonov AN-225](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225)  holds the record for a payload of over 253 metric tons. That would solve the weight issue, even if you need to carry a few tons of sea water around the whale. The cargo hold is pressurized and slightly over 43 meters long, 10 meters longer than the whale.

Unfortunately, the service ceiling of the AN-225 is only 11'000 meters, 4 km short of our goal.

Given the fact that we can use all of earth's ressources, it should be fairly simple to modify the aircraft to be able to fly 4 km higher, since there have been quite some aircraft designed for these altitudes, and conversions have been done, too, so it should simply be a question of funding, which in this context is no problem, and of doing it.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

I have no answer for your question, I just wanted to introduce you to the Skywhale. It was commisioned for Canberra's 100th Anniversary and has been roving the skies around the world for the last year.

[image: Skywhale]

Comment: that is... weird. And funny.

Comment: Only in Australia. Though, they should have made a drop bear.

Comment: @Kristy nice I get the picture whale is a mammal but do they have to make it that obvious